# soy newbie intentando hacer una colección

Tags: java, arraylist, colecciones

no tengo muy fundamentado la idea de como crear una colección(historial)de un objeto de otra clase(pagina)llevo horas y horas tratando de hacerme idea de como instanciar una colección con un arraylist y como recorrerla para que el elemento cero sea el ultimo ingresado en teoría creo tenerlo mas o menos idealizado pero no me conozco la sintaxis correctamente.
1)clase pagina.

```
**import java.util.Date;
    **public class Pagina {
        private String url;
        private Date fechaDeUltimaVisita;
        private double tamaño;
        private String codeHtml;
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Pagina{" +
                    "url='" + url + '\'' +
                    ", fechaDeUltimaVisita=" + fechaDeUltimaVisita +
                    ", tmaño=" + tamaño +
                    ", codeHtml='" + codeHtml + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }
        public void setFechaDeUltimaVisita(Date fechaDeUltimaVisita) {
            this.fechaDeUltimaVisita = fechaDeUltimaVisita;
        }
        public void setTamaño(double tamaño) {
            this.tamaño = tamaño;
        }
        public void setCodeHtml(String codeHtml) {
            this.codeHtml = codeHtml;
        }
        public Pagina(String url, Date fechaDeUltimaVisita, double tamaño, 
String codeHtml) {
        this.url = url;
        this.fechaDeUltimaVisita = fechaDeUltimaVisita;
        this.tamaño = tamaño;
        this.codeHtml = codeHtml;
    }
}
2)clase historial.
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Historial {
   public Historial(ArrayList<Pagina> historial) {
      this.historial = historial;
   }
   private ArrayList<Pagina>historial=new ArrayList<>();
   public ArrayList<Pagina> getHistorial() {
      return historial;
   }
   public void setHistorial(ArrayList<Pagina> historial) {
      this.historial = historial;
   }
}****
```

Comment: y qué has intentado para que recorrerla para que el elemento cero sea el ultimo ingresado?

Comment: emular una pila con el (index,elemento).

Comment: puedes poner el código de tus intentos para ver cómo piensas?